# How to create custom property of Term in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

i have tried following code it creates term but it gives me insufficient permission error when creating CustomProperty.

```
private void CreateNewNavigationElement()
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                var allowUnsafeUpdate = sitecollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                sitecollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                var session = new TaxonomySession(sitecollection);
                var termStore = session.TermStores["xxx"];
                var group = termStore.Groups["yyy"];
                var navigationTermSet = group.TermSets["zzz"];
                var term = navigationTermSet.CreateTerm("testTitle", 1031);
                CreateCustomLocalProperties(term);
                navigationTermSet.TermStore.CommitAll();
            });    
        }
    }

private void CreateCustomLocalProperties(Term childTerm)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
       childTerm.SetLocalCustomProperty("CustomProperty", "Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using elevation, and tags the question with "app"? You can not use elevation in the app model this way

Comment: To be fair, you should just remove them above since you are not doing any elevation in either case